# how to detect whether request is coming from browser or smartphone?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, smartphone

I am having a web application , which works fine .
now there is a particular page which gets bulky when i access the application from smartphone browser , so I wanted a situation like

```
if(request comes from computer browser client )
forward to bulky page in web application
else
if (request comes from smartphone )
forward to some other light page .
```

please put your suggestion how can i achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the user-agent. Every connection to your server carries this header, by convenience and convention. There is no guarantee that a browser will be truthful(such as a spambot reporting itself as Chrome). You can get the user-agent as follows:

```
request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

and then check again known user-agent strings and templates.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally done by checking "User-Agent" header of Request